# Kinect mapping color image to depth image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, kinect, matlab-cvst, kinect-sdk

I have collected data using Kinect v2 sensor and I have a depth map together with its corresponding RGB image. I also calibrated the sensor and obtained the rotation and translation matrix between the Depth camera and RGB camera.

So I was able to reproject the depth values on the RGB image and they match. However, since the RGB image and the depth image are of different resolutions, there are a lot of holes in the resulting image.

So I am trying to move the other way, i.e. mapping the color onto the depth instead of depth to color.

So the first problem I am having is that the RGB image has 3 layers and I have to convert the RGB image to grayscale to do it and I am not getting the correct results.

Can this be done?

Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you fit the Z-depth to the RGB?

To fit the low res image to the high- res should be easy, as long as both represent the same size of data (i.e. corners of both images are the same point)

It should be as easy as:

```
Z_interp=imresize(Zimg, [size(RGB,1) size(RGB,2)])
```

Now `Z_interp` should have the same amount of pixels as RGB

---

If you still want to do it the other way around, well, use the same approach:

```
RGB_interp=imresize(RGB, [size(Zimg,1) size(Zimg,2)])
```

Answer (score -1):

The Image Acquisition Toolbox now officially supports [Kinect v2 for Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/kinect-windows.html). You can get a point cloud out from Kinect using [pcfromkinect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfromkinect.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.